# Running Scheme from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, scheme

How do you run Scheme programs from the terminal in linux(ubuntu)? Also how to accept arguments from the command-line in a Scheme program?

Edit: Im using the DrScheme implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DrScheme scheme implementation, and the name you use to execute it from the command line, is `mzscheme`. The documentation for starting a command line script is found here: [Unix Scripts (PLT Scheme documentation)](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/scripts.html). Use of the command line args is explained here: [Command-line Parsing (PLT Scheme Documentation)](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/Command-Line_Parsing.html).

The upshot is that you can use shebang scripts like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env mzscheme
#lang scheme/base
(...scheme s-exps...)
```

or if you want more control over the command line flags for `mzscheme`, you need to start the script like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
#|
exec mzscheme -cu "$0" ${1+"$@"}
|#
#lang scheme/base
(...scheme s-exps...)
```

The function you use to process command line args is `command-line`. You will find examples of how to use it in the article linked to by the second link.

Comment: Note also that to test such a script from DrScheme, you can pop up the language selection dialog (ctrl+L), then click the "show details" button, and on the right you'll have a place to enter the command line arguments that your script will see.

Comment: How would it work with MIT Scheme? I cannot find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 3):

It is not standardized in the [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/). There is a recommendation [SRFI-22](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-22/srfi-22.html), which some interpreters support. If your interpreter does not support SRFI-22 then it depends on your implementation.

Below is an example from the SRFI. It assumes your interpreter is a binary named scheme-r5rs. Basically it calls a function named main with a single arg that is a list of command line args.

```
#! /usr/bin/env scheme-r5rs

(define (main arguments)
  (for-each display-file (cdr arguments))
  0)

(define (display-file filename)
  (call-with-input-file filename
    (lambda (port)
      (let loop ()
    (let ((thing (read-char port)))
      (if (not (eof-object? thing))
          (begin
        (write-char thing)
        (loop))))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me

```
#! /usr/bin/env guile
!#

(display "hello")
(newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also how to accept arguments from the
>   command-line in a Scheme program?

The R6RS library defines a function called [`command-line`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-11.html#node_chap_10) which returns the list of the arguments (the first one being the name of the program). Not all implementations of Scheme implement R6RS though; your implementation might have some other function for this.

> How do you run Scheme programs from
>   the terminal in linux(ubuntu)?

It depends on which implementation of Scheme you're using.

Answer (score 0):

LINUX bash:
$ cat myfile.scm | scheme

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).