# getting command line arguments in Scheme using `command-line` function

Tags: command-line, arguments, scheme, r6rs

This question has definitely been asked before, [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175977/running-scheme-from-the-command-line). Some of the solutions presented did work(in Windows) except for the `command-line` function mentioned in [Command-line access and exit values](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-11.html) in `r6rs-lib`.

I managed to achieve what I wanted in `Gauche`(non r6rs compliant implementation) using `*argv*`:

```
(display *argv*)
> gosh test.ss first 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
         >> (first 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)
```

I want to do the same with `Petite Chez Scheme` which is `r6rs` compliant using the `command-line` function. I've tried to use the code in that chapter but all I get is a list with the script's name and only the first argument. e.g

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs programs (6)))
(display (command-line))

> petite --script test.ss first second
    >> (test.ss first)
```

**Is there some other library import I'm missing that would make it work**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following 'script' works for me in 'Ikarus Scheme':

```
#!/usr/bin/env scheme-script
(import (rnrs))
(display (command-line))
(newline)

ebg@ebg$ ./ik.scm a b c
(./ik.scm a b c)
ebg@ebg$ ikarus --r6rs-script ./ik.scm a b c
(./ik.scm a b c)
```

and for Petite

```
ebg@ebg$ petite --script ~/ik.scm a b c
(/Users/ebg/ik.scm a b c)
```

Note that officially `(import (rnrs programs (6)))` won't import `display` so as written your code should fail.

Comment: Guess what, the code runs as intended in `Ubuntu`. Maybe the `Petite` windows installation is broken. Does it work for you in `Windows`?

Comment: I've no Windows machine to try.  Please up-vote and perhaps mark as 'answered'.

Comment: I think I'm going to give it some more time for someone with Windows to chip in. I think there's something wrong with the way that function is implemented in Windows because even Racket does not return all the values. I tried it with your code(mine raised an error like you said) and it returned `{C:\mine\.ss\test.ss}`. Is anybody else getting the same in Windows?

Comment: Yeah, it is. I guess no one uses scheme in Windows. Might as well accept your answer.